# Thread returning into bad space address

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, firebreath

I have a weird problem regarding the use of threads inside a Firebreath plugin (in this case a FB plugin, but could happen anywhere); I will try to explain:

- 1) My plugin creates a thread (static), and it receives a pointer to "this" every time it gets added to a page.
- 2) So, now I have a thread with a pointer to the plugin, so I can call it's methods.
- 3) Very nice so far, BUT, suppose that I have a button (coded in HTML), which when pressed will REMOVE the current plugin, put in place another one and launch another thread.

I have described my scenario, now for the problem, when a plugin gets added it launches a thread; inside the thread there is a pointer to "this". First time, it gets fired...while the thread is executing I press the HTML button (so, the current plugin now is destroyed) and a new one is placed. The thread from the 1st plugin ends, and now returns...but it returns to the 2nd instance of the plugin.

The plugin is an image viewer, the first plugin look for a picture, it gets removed and a new one is placed; BUT the image from the 1st plugin is placed in the 2nd one. I don't know where to start looking, apparently the pointer has an address to the plugin (e.g. 12345), the plugin gets removed and instantiated again with the same memory address (12345).

Is there some way to avoid that behavior?

This is the code I have so far:

**myPlugin.h**

```
unsigned ThreadId; 
HANDLE hThread;
```

**myPlugin.cpp**

```
unsigned __stdcall myPlugin::Thread(void *data)
{  
        myPlugin* this = (myPlugin*) data; 
        this->getImage("http:\\host.com\\image.jpg");  
    _endthreadex(0); //EDIT: addedd this missing line to end the thread
}
void myPlugin::onPluginReady(std::string imageUrl) 
{  
    hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, myPlugin::Thread, (void*) **this**, 0, &ThreadId); 
}
void myPlugin::getImage() 
{  
    //get an image using CURL... //no problem here 
}
```

Comment: Where's the code that ends the thread ? There should be some place where you 1. Request the thread to end. 2. wait for it to end. 3. unload the plugin.

Comment: Added `_endthreadex(0);` into the `Thread` function. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is how it's done. Regarding the steps you mention; 1) is it possible to request a thread to end from outside the thread process? 2) If I wait for it to end, I will have a delay; isn't it? 3) The unload process is fired by the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop and join the thread in the shutdown() function of your Plugin class; that will be called before things are actually unloaded and that will help avoid the problem.

I would also recommend using boost::thread, since FireBreath already compiles it all in, and that will help simplify some of this; you can hold a weak_ptr in your thread to the plugin class rather than passing in a void*.  Of course, either way you'll need to stop and join the thread during the plugin shutdown (and the thread needs to stop *quickly* or the browser will get cranky about it taking so long).